# jQuery basic authentication doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, cors

I need to make a CORS request to server which uses basic authentication. I use jQuery 1.5.1 and have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    global: true,
    url: theSource,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ABC.ABCconsole.log('Success');
        ABC.openAjaxSuccess(data);
    }
});
```

On a server side setted these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

Unfortunately in response from server I have `401 Unauthorized` error.

In a **request** I have these headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:example01.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/france/asd/qwes/business-nothing.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
```

And in a **response** these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Content-Length:58
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 16 Jul 2014 09:42:00 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie:loc=phl;path=/;
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="example01.com"
```

May be you have any ideas why it happens?

**UPD:** As you can see in a request I don't see that my `Authentication` header is setted. If I running browser with `--disable-web-security` key everything works fine. And `Authentication` header is setted properly.

**UPD2:** Request fails on a http POST method. So may be problem is here?

```
Remote Address:111.111.11.12:80
Request URL:http://example01.com/asst/index.epx?id=569fe9d0-1515-423a-bae8-84265b6396a0&_=1405506291028
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: I think the server is responding with what it knows. Authorisation failed. Is the username and password correct? Run wireshark and look at the request at the network level and compare that to accessing the same page in your web browser, so check that the basic authentication is working, and tinker with it. Or use fiddler for the tinkering. Perhaps take a look here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax>

Comment: @ActionDan unfortunately credentials are correct. If I requesting url from browser I get login form. Bot it doesn't work with jQuery CORS request. In a response i get only 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` instead.

Comment: I have no access to remote server. This header setted to only one value for security policy.

Comment: Then configure your local development machine to use same example.com, instead of 'localhost' or something.

Comment: I make request also from remote server. All I can it's editing js in Chrome.

Comment: Install **Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest** chrome extension. enable it and see if it works